# Auth.log entries: How do you interpret this log?

Tags: ssh, login, sshd

There has been some odd behavior on my server. I pulled up the auth.log and found this (this is not my IP):

```
Sep 16 16:38:23 xxxxxx sshd[750]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=194.59.249.21  user=root
Sep 16 16:38:25 xxxxxx sshd[750]: Failed password for root from 194.59.249.21 port 49252 ssh2
Sep 16 16:38:29 xxxxxx sshd[750]: Accepted password for root from 194.59.249.21 port 49252 ssh2
Sep 16 16:38:29 xxxxxx sshd[750]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
.....
Sep 16 18:49:49 xxxxxx sshd[750]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user root
```

I'm reading this as:

1. Someone tried to login at 16:38:25 and failed password.
2. 4 seconds later they type in the correct password and gets in to the server (first attempt must therefor be a typo).
3. 2 hours and 10 minutes later they log out.

Is my interpretation correct? If so, is there another log that shows me what they did?

Comment: "10 minutes later they log out." - wrong - about 2 hours 10 minutes later they logout.

Comment: Correct. Typo on my end

Comment: Great, for what it's worth, there's a huge benefit in adding 'PermitRootLogin no' to your sshd_config and restarting ssh for it to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

Your interpretation is correct.

If you want to see all commands they run you need to look in the users history file

As this user is root it will be in /root/.bash_history

For other users it would be /home/username/.bash_history

If they ran privileged commands it may be in /var/log/secure however as they are the root user likely not as they don't need to use sudo.